# ReactJS & Firebase: How to fill the home page dynamically from Firebase Database

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am a super-newbie in ReactJS. I have a course project deployed on Firebase (I have not dynamically scaled for different resolutions, it is better on mobile right now): https://clean-kitchen.web.app/

For now, recipes are hardcoded in the following way:

```
class Home extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {};
  }
  componentDidMount() {}
  componentWillUnmount() {}

  render() {
      return <>
          <GridCategory />
          <Paper elevation={0} square style={{ marginTop: "8px", marginBottom: "8px", padding: "8px"}}>
          <HeaderSuggestion title="Popular" icon="fire.png" />
          <GridSuggestion recipe="pasta alla carbonara" img="carbonara.jpg" />
          </Paper>
          <Paper elevation={0} square style={{ marginTop: "8px", marginBottom: "8px", padding: "8px"}}>
          <HeaderSuggestion title="Editor's Choice" icon="choice.png" />
          <GridSuggestion recipe="Cheesecake" img="cheesecake.jpg" />
          </Paper>
      </>
  }
}
```

My goal is to fetch the current recipes from the real-time database and create the page dynamically. Database design on Firebase is as follows:

[image]

I am trying to fetch the database node in the following way, but I cannot iterate on this by using forEach method.

```
var recipes = fire.database().ref("node_recipes/recipes");
```

How can I correctly iterate on this variable and pass the recipe name and image URL into "GridSuggestion"? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To iterate an array and return a JSX element for each element of that array you use `map`. You cab do something like this:

```
{recipes.map(recipe => (
    <GridSuggestion key={recipe.id} recipe={recipe.title} img={recipe.overviewImg} />
))}
```

If you want to include more content in the looping, like your `Paper` and `HeaderSuggestion` components, just add then in the return of the map

Comment: Thank you for the answer! However, I'm getting error in this way. It is related the way I fetch the data from the database (because it is TypeError), but I don't know what is wrong.
https://pasteboard.co/JI4gtkO.png
https://pasteboard.co/JI4gCW1.png

Comment: The error literally says the problem. `recipes` is not an array. Do a console log of `fire.database().ref("node_recipes/recipes")` and see if you get an array. If not, try to find where the array is. `map` is a function to loop arrays. I assumed `recipes` was already an array from what you said and posted

Comment: As you have said, error was related to the returning data type and I fixed it. Thanks!

Comment: No problem, glad I could help!